# need help about add navigationItem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem

[image]

As you see in the images, the top picture is created automatically when navigation controller is pushed

If I try to create one like this it will appear like the bottom picture.

How can I programmatically create a Back Button like the top picture?

Here is my code to create the Done button

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(backtohome)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *theBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = theBackButton;
[theBackButton release];
```